# C++ - how to tell whether a key exists in map of maps

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following structure:

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> my_map;
```

I want to check whether the key `my_map[3][5]` exists.

Is there any easier/shorter way to do so except for something like:

```
if (my_map.find(3) != my_map.end()) {
    std::map<int, int>& internal_map = my_map[3];
    if (internal_map.find(5) != internal_map.end()) {
        // ... Do something ...
    }
}
```

Comment: For one, you can use `count()` instead of `find`.

Comment: I have more than one key in the primary map and more than 1 key in the internal map

Comment: That doesn't matter.

Comment: Oh - `count()` means count of a specific key? But this is a map - the count can be only 0 or 1, am I wrong? Don't new values with same key override the former ones?

Comment: Is `count()` better in performance than `find()` ?

Comment: You're checking whether an item exists in a map, and `count` does exactly that. Yes, it can only be 0 or 1 for a `map` or `set`. It's the same complexity as `find`, may or may not be a tad faster (it doesn't have to construct an iterator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could improve it a little via:

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, int>>::iterator it = my_map.find(3);
if (it != my_map.end()){
    if (it->second.find(5) != internal_map.end()) {
    }
}
```

In your current solution, you are finding the key twice and it could be slower than finding it once and store it in iterator.

Comment: Is there something more simple in manners of code? Or we have code the checking of both maps? (like you and me have already done)

Comment: Depends what you want from it. Instead of two keys, you can use std::tupple (C++11) or std::pair as your key and have only one map

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
int k  = 3;
int k1 = 5;

std::map<int, int>::iterator it = my_map[k].end();

if( (my_map.find(k))->second.find(k1) != it ){
    std::cout << "something";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What will happen if `k` is not a key in the primary map? Is it ok that you try to reach `->second` and its method? Can't it be some undefined object?

Comment: this is UB if `k` does not exist

Comment: my English is not very good, but your question is correct, if I prove not exist, and the compiler, permitting, i was reading this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/ this parte return value An iterator to the element, if an element with specified key is found, or map::end otherwise. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/end/ I think there should be no problem, because compared with != it1, before using I also wondered the same thing and no probem tube, but I'm not an expert,

Comment: I just thought this might help, but it can be a response that causes some unwanted behavior I delete